# Woocommerce custom products page of a category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to create a new menu item under woocommerce section, 
The menu item should create a products page of a custom given category.

Comment: Have you found any code examples to do this?  I am sure if you searched you could.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in standard wordpress menu. Go to appearance -> menu -> add store category to menu.